# Definition of a Homologous Series

Tags: organic-chemistry, terminology, hydrocarbons

My textbook states that members of a homologous series have the same general formula (ex. $\ce{C_{n}H_{2n}}$ for alkenes) as they only differ from one to another by additional $\ce{CH_2}$ (methylene) groups. However, alkenes can have more than 1 carbon-carbon double bond, which should alter their general formula right?

Comment: Luke [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homologous_series) for good definition and description.

Comment: @MathewMahindaratne Are you suggesting that members of a homologous series need not have the general formula, only the same functional group?

Comment: Read carefully and look at examples given.

Comment: There is the series for dienes and whatever number of double bounds you may wish to count and classify. Also , if the number of double bounds gets higher, usually trends and comparison is interesting with respect of the latter different n. This leads to a series, in a way, except that is of analogous rather than homologous - oligo- and polyenes.

Comment: If a molecule has more than one double bond C=C, it is not an alkene. It is an alkadiene, or an alkapolyene.